# From where does the Python 'pip' tool get the packages it installs?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed a few packages using Command Prompt on Windows. For example:

To upgrade pip version I used the command:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

To install discord.py package I used the command:

`python -m pip install -U discord.py`

> Out of curiosity... How do these commands work? From where do they get downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're asking where the packages come from...from the Cheese Shop, of course :)

> Python Package Index The Python Package Index (abbreviated as PyPI)
>   and also known as the Cheese Shop is the official third-party software
>   repository for Python. It primarily hosts Python packages in the form
>   of archives called 'sdists' (source distributions) or precompiled
>   wheels (you will see this later). In a sentence: PyPI is as a giant
>   online repository of modules that are accepted by the Python
>   community.

https://pypi.org/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `pip` is exclusively for Python packages (it comes with Python), and the PiPi repository is just for Python packages.

Comment: When you start a command using Python... Does cmd automatically connect to www.pypi.org to download the necessary package?

Comment: When you run `pip install`, it downloads the package you have specified, and installs it into your Python installation as a local package.  When you run a Python program that uses that package, it gets it from your local disk, because `pip` has already installed it there.  So YES, `pip` does automatically connect to `www.pypi.org`.  `pip` can also be used to install a package you've downloaded and have in a local file on your machine.

Comment: Alright! Thanks. Only Python packages can be installed this way?

Comment: Yes, that's right. - Each language pretty much has their own way of doing this same sort of thing.

Comment: Are Python packages downloaded from public servers in the user's region of the country? For example, nearby university computer science departments.